# Trying to get title of table using python docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I have a Word DOCX in the following format:

```
Title

 - text

Title1

 - Description

Title2
 - Definition
 - Table2
 - text

Title3

 - Definition
 - Table3
 - text
...
```

I am using python docx, and would like to get the "title" that matches with every "table" (ie the title that is closest to the table, so title2 with table2). Is there a way of doing this?

I know we could iterate through the doc like this:

```
for para in doc.paragraphs:
     print(para.text)
```

but that would make it hard to match title to table. Is there a better approach to doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This thread in the GitHub issues list might be helpful:
https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/40

If you add an iter_block_items() function, make sure you use the one at toward the end of the thread, it's had to evolve a bit over time since it makes use of internals that are subject to change.